# Why my Python 3.1 POST code doesn't send data properly?

Tags: python, http, post

I'd like to make a post like this, using Python 3.1 (I just used the "Copy as cURL" on firefox):

```
curl 'http://some.example.test/formulario.php?current_date=31%2F08%2F2015&Button_Insert=Include&ccsForm=apropriacao' -H 'Host: some.example.test' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Referer: http://some.example.test/formulario.php?current_date=31%2F08%2F2015&Button_Insert=Confirm&Button_Insert=Include' -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=ctbsuli3i6f6mivof2dv9mb036; SERVERID=X' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data 'TextBox3=OK&idservice=14&idactivity=16&idsistem=1&TextBox1=&idproject=9&TextBox2=100&Button_Insert=Include&current_date=31%2F08%2F2015'
```

I've made many searches on stackoverflow, and I make this code (only the necessary parts shown):

```
dataPostJson = {'TextBox3': 'OK', 'idservice': '14' etc}
params = json.dumps(dataPostJson).encode('utf8')

req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=params)

req.add_header('Host', 'some.example.test')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0')
...
req.add_header('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')

response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

Even with response.getcode() == 200, the POST doesn't change values on the Host. If I try to execute this cURL command, the POST occurs properly, so the problem isn't the Host. The problem is with my code.

Can someone give me a clue?

EDIT:

What I'm trying to do is:
1) log in a server with my credentials
2) get PHPSESSID and SERVERID returned
3) add data to the server with HTTP POST

Things to consider: when I do a get to login.php, the server already gives me a PHPSESSID and SERVERID. When I POST my credentials {'login': '...', 'password': '...', 'sendButton': 'buttonValue'}, I don't know how to check if user/password was sent correctly.

I can see that, if I do a login via browser, take PHPSESSID and SERVERID, and replace them into the cURL command, I can send data to the server. But, using python, I'm not getting the same sucess.

Comment: your trying to send a json body as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. use [`urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) instead of json to encode your data.

Comment: you mean params = urllib.parse.urlencode(dataPostJson)? it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to encode it to bytes, see the [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib-examples) for reference. or use the [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org) library, which offers a much easier to use api.

Comment: I changed params = json.dumps(dataPostJson).encode('utf8') to params = urllib.parse.urlencode(dataPostJson).encode('utf8');

I changed req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=params) to req = urllib.request.Request(url)


The last change: from response = urllib.request.urlopen(req) to response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, params)



I don't want to use requests because it doesn't work on Python 3.1 and I don't like to "downgrade" the application.

Comment: @Paulinho Are you sure about `requests`? I found that Requests currently supports the following versions of Python:

    Python 2.6,
    Python 2.7,
    Python 3.1,
    Python 3.2,
    Python 3.3. Have you already tried `requests`?

Comment: D:\Python31>python.exe --version
Python 3.1.2

D:\Python31>python.exe F:\rh3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\rh3.py", line 11, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests

Comment: Why you think that it's not working? Is there a `requests` module folder in `D:\Python31\Lib\site-packages` ?

Comment: No, there isn't. Only a readme.txt. I'm trying to find how to install requests module.

I think it's not working because, after the POST, I do the login and search for the data (sent by the POST) on the website, and the data is not there.

When I use cURL no command prompt, the data is sent.

Comment: seems that `requests` is not installed, so you can use `pip install requests` or `easy_install requests` (from cmd/terminal) and then there will be no `ImportError`

Comment: Ok, easy_install was not installed on my computer, but I found this file ez_install.py on the internet that installed easy_install. Now, requests is installed. I'll try to manage this code to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I properly "translated" everything from `cUrl` request to `python requests`, but try following (after installing `requests` package) and let me know result:

```
import requests

url = 'http://some.example.test /formulario.php?current_date=31%2F08%2F2015&Button_Insert=Include&ccsForm=apropriacao'
headers = {
    'Host':'some.example.test',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Referer': 'http://some.example.test/formulario.php?current_date=31%2F08%2F2015&Button_Insert=Confirm&Button_Insert=Include',
    'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=ctbsuli3i6f6mivof2dv9mb036; SERVERID=X',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }

payload = {
    'TextBox3': 'OK',
    'idservice': '14',
    'idactivity': '16',
    'idsistem': '1',
    'TextBox1': '',
    'idproject': '9',
    'TextBox2': '100',
    'Button_Insert': 'Include',
    'current_date': '31%2F08%2F2015'
    }

r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Still not working. One doubt: in current_date, do I need to use %2F instead of slash? Another one: the field "Button_Insert" that must has the value "Include" is not exactly "Include". The correct value is "Include Something" (can you see the space?). When I get the cURL command, the space is replaced by a plus sign. On python code, do I have to keep the + sign or can I use the space character?

Comment: 1) Well, I don't know exactly how your web app expect to receive date, but yes, in fact `'31%2F08%2F2015' == '31/08/2015'` so yo should try. 2) No, I'm afraid I see no spaces...

Comment: I see that there is a GET request used in another GET request as URI. Maybe you should try to use `url = 'http://some.example.test /formulario.php'` and add one more key-value pair to `payload` - `'ccsForm': 'apropriacao'` ? just assumption